# What is readline history used for in PHP?

Tags: php, shell

I'm planning on creating a PHP driven script to be run from a command line. So I was looking at how PHP handles input and came across the [Readline page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php) on php.net. The example on this page uses the **readline_add_history** function:

```
<?php
//get 3 commands from user
for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $line = readline("Command: ");
        readline_add_history($line);
}

//dump history
print_r(readline_list_history());

//dump variables
print_r(readline_info());
?>
```

My question is why would you use **readline_add_history** and **readline_list_history** over a normal array or even a string. Would this work the same way?

```
<?php
//get 3 commands from user
$input = '';
for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $input .= readline("Command: ") . "\n";
}

//dump input
print_r($input);

//dump variables
print_r(readline_info());
?>
```

I ask this because I couldn't find any obvious explanation. Perhaps there are other advantages to the functions in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of adding the line to the history is that the user can then hit up-arrow to select the previous line, or use Ctrl-R to search for one, without having to type it from scratch.

This is very useful when you want to adapt a previous command and submit it again.